# Read and Write to text file in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to add values in a textfile. Its working well and output is good in eclipse.
But when i see the values in file, i get a straight pattern : 2526272829.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class FileDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bfr;
        String line;    
        bfr=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fileName=bfr.readLine();
        File file=new File(fileName);       
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }       
        try{
            bfr=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            while((line=bfr.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(file,true);            
            for(int i=25;i<30;i++){                 
                fw.append(String.valueOf(i));
            }

            while((line=bfr.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            bfr.close();
            fw.close();

        }catch(FileNotFoundException fex){
            fex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and i also want to know how bufferedReader storage works so please give some links.

Comment: [All you need](http://goo.gl/lIsLZZ)

Comment: What kind of output were you expecting?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Did you notice that you write something different to `System.out` and to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append new line to the FileWriter on each iteration, but do it right, don't concatenate strings.

```
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(file,true);            
for(int i=25;i<30;i++){    
    fw.append(String.valueOf(i)); 
    fw.append("\n"); 
}
```

Comment: Do it right? What's wrong with concatenating strings?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, add manually a new line:

```
fw.append(String.valueOf(i) + "\n");
```

Comment: fw.append(String.valueOf(i));  fw.append("\n");

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a newline character in your for loop:

```
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(file,true);            
for(int i=25; i<30; i++) {                 
    fw.append(String.valueOf(i)+"\n"); // Here I've made the small correction
}
```

This will write on a new line each time you append. I'm assuming this is the output you wanted.

For `bufferedReader` information you can look here for more information:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: fw.append(String.valueOf(i)); fw.append("\n");